# Change global variable from alias in ZSH?

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

Does anyone know if it's possible to change a global variable with an alias in ZSH, e.g:

`.zshrc`

```
MYVAR=foo

alias bar=[Enter something to change MYVAR to "bar" here.]
```

Then use the alias in the terminal:

```
$ echo $MYVAR
foo
$ bar
$ echo $MYVAR
bar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes... The command to set the variable `MYVAR` to `bar` is `MYVAR=bar`, so you can put that in your alias:

```
$ MYVAR=foo
$ alias bar='MYVAR=bar'
$ echo $MYVAR
foo
$ bar
$ echo $MYVAR
bar
```

Answer (score 1):

The question shouldn't be "Can I define an alias to...", but "Is there a reason to use an alias *instead of a function* to ...". In this case, the answer appears to be  "no".

```
$ bar () { MYVAR=bar; }
$ bar
$ echo $MYVAR
bar
```